# Unable to extract zip in python to destination folder(server) from my local host

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I'm unable to extract zip file in python to destination folder(server) from my local host. While extracting using `z.extract(name,"/destination/")`, it's unable to find destination folder as it is trying to search destination folder locally instead of the server.

```
    transport = paramiko.Transport((destinationIP))
    transport.connect(username = destinationuserName, password =   destinationPassword)
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

    fh = sftp.open('/destination/xxx.zip', 'rb')
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(fh)
    for name in z.namelist():
        print name
        z.extract(name,"/destination/") 
    fh.close()
    sftp.close()
```

Comment: Any reason why you are not using scp and tar ?

Comment: no reason, any idea d-coder

Comment: I assume you are running this script on local host.. if yes then.. YES your script will search your local only..

Comment: yes..u r right. i am running this in my local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you would like the extracted files to appear on the server, even though you are extracting them on the client machine. Unfortunately that isn't going to fly, as the `zipfile.extract` method assumes that its second argument is a local path.

You *could* consider creating a local temporary directory in which to extract the files, but then you will have to copy each file back to its desired destination on the server. This doesn't seem like a sensible use of distributed resources, but if you don't have shell access to the server it might be the best you can do.

If you *do* have shell access to the server then consider using something like `fabric` or `paramiko` to execute the necessary commands on the server system.